# How do I figure the weighted mean of headings?

Tags: netlogo, heading, weighted-average

[Get mean heading of neighboring turtles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786908/get-mean-heading-of-neighboring-turtles)

```
to-report mean-heading [ headings ]
  let mean-x mean map sin headings
  let mean-y mean map cos headings
  report atan mean-x mean-y
end
```

from that answer gets me part way there but I want is each of the headings to be weighted on size of the turtles.

something like

```
 sum [heading * size] of turtles / sum [size] of turtles
```

But that would, you know, actually work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you accept a turtleset instead of a list of headings, then:

```
to-report weighted-mean-heading [turts]
  let mean-x mean [size * sin heading] of turts
  let mean-y mean [size * cos heading] of turts
  report atan mean-x mean-y
end
```

Comment: That seems right I have to test it a bit first though.

Comment: Thank you. You have just answered this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749916/need-help-on-speeding-up-a-particle-system-or-how-to-ask-turtles-not-to-ask-oth